# Convert polygons (in the image) to masks

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection

I have some images and their associated ground truth outlined objects. For example this image shows the outlined objects for one of the original images[outlined objects in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXopr.png)

Given this image and its original source, I would like to create some masks based on these outlines using openCV2 or skimage.

Using Contours I can roughly achieve that, but I have two problems:

1- Why I get repeated masks? (plz refer to the attached snippet)
2- How to overcome the issue of two touching objects

```
from skimage import io
from skimage import measure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = io.imread('path/to/the/attached/image')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours = measure.find_contours(gray, 0.1)
for n, contour in enumerate(contours):
r_mask = np.zeros_like(gray, dtype='bool')
r_mask[np.round(contour[:, 0]).astype('int'), np.round(contour[:, 
1]).astype('int')] = 1

r_mask = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(r_mask)
io.imshow(r_mask)
plt.show()
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Ideally, you would add some code to show the community the efforts you have already made to solve the issue ...

Comment: I have added my attempt to produce masks using contours